# Why does a particular person not receive my Google Calendar event invitations?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

When I send event invitations through Google Calendar, there is one person listed that does not receive the invitation. All others in the list receive it.

He is on gMail too and has checked his spam folder. Other emails from me he receives ok. Is there some other setting he needs to change to receive the invitations?

Answer (score 22):

This is likely because of he has explicitly denied sending notifications about events to him.

> Ask the guest to make sure that they didn't turn off email notifications for new events. If they use Google Calendar, ask the guest to check their email notifications while on a computer.

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37161?hl=en&ref_topic=3417969

To change this setting:

1. Open calendar (you can't do this from mobile apps!)
2. Click on gear/cog and choose settings
3. On the left side under `Settings for my calendars` select the calendar for which invite was targeted.
4. Scroll down to General notifications and enable new events notifications

[image: Screen capture of the General notifications section in the calendar settings]

Comment: This answer is a little stale now. I could not find "how you would like to be notified" in the settings. It's probably been changed.

Comment: @jcollum updated answer, maybe that helps

Comment: Once you are in Calendar Settings you have to click on the calendar name to see the notifications options.

Comment: **NOTE:** the answer above is correct but the heading under which these notification settings are stored has been changed. They are now under a section named _Other notifications_ and, as @CecilyCrout points out, you must first select the correct calendar on the left-side, assuming you maintain more than one calendar in your account.

Answer (score 0):

The setting in Google Calendar is in General -> Add invitations to my calendar

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question. It isn't about adding invitations to the calendar it is about receiving invitation  emails.  If the highly upvoted answer hasn't yet been updated per the comment of Mar 23, 2020, it would be helpful if  you edited that answer  to improve it based on the info in the comment.